# Force NFS to search nobody user only locally (/etc/passwd)

Tags: ldap, nfs, solaris

I have a server solaris with files and ldap as NSS repository and a NFS server.

Every time the NFS service is invoked, it procced with a search of the user nobody on ldap nevertheless the user is locally.

Is there a way to configure NFS to search exclusively on local files and prevent it to look outside the server?

Thank you
Daniel

Comment: Change the order of sources for lookup in **/etc/nsswitch.conf** file.

Comment: the order is "files ldap". what do you suggest?

Comment: looks correct to me.

Comment: You could try adding an additional files entry.  
ie:
  passwd: files files ldap

Perhaps the entry is also being resolved by the cachemgr which you could also try disabling.